# Htaccess проблема

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Делаю ЧПУ для сайта возникла проблема, если стоит правило

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/([^/]*)$ index.php?name=$2 [QSA]
```

То сайт перенаправляет к примеру:

```
/mouse/ultra => index.php?name=ultra
```

Но если запросить форум:

```
/forum/mytheme => index.php?name=mytheme
```

То есть если соответствует, то все URL сайт так преобразуются. Что делать? Как добавить исключения? Помимо /forum/mytheme есть и /user/admin - вообщем проблема во всем.

**Добавлено для [[@VenZell](/users/13336/venzell)](/users/13336/venzell)**
Содержимое htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^user\/([^/])\/$ user.php?act=$1
RewriteRule ^forum\/([^/])\/$ forum.php?act=$1 
RewriteRule ^([^/])\/([^/])\/$ index.php?do=filter&sort=$2 [QSA]
```

Проблема, если зайти по адресу к примеру: 
`/user/profile/` - меня перекидывает на `index.php` (ну вы поняли) 
По последнему правилу, а не по тому что надо. 
Как обоити это? Чтобы при `/user/profile/` открывало user/profile ? А не перекидывало на index.php

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/mytheme$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/admin$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/([^/]*)$ index.php?name=$2 [QSA]
```

Или

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/admin.*
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/([^/]*)$ index.php?name=$2 [QSA]
```

В зависимости от того, что вам надо

Comment: Это работает если /forum/mytheme - это тоже ЧПУ:

RewriteRule ^forum\/([^/]*)\/$ forum.php?act=$1

Comment: @Neshok, после вашего комментария я совершенно перестал понимать, что вы хотите сделать. Пример, как прописать исключение, я указал. Уточните, что должно получиться в итоге.

Comment: Содержимое htaccess:\n
RewriteEngine On\n
RewriteRule ^user\/([^/]*)\/$ user.php?act=$1\n
RewriteRule ^forum\/([^/]*)\/$ forum.php?act=$1\n
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/$ index.php?do=filter&sort=$2 [QSA]\n\n

Вот проблема, если зайти по адресу к примеру: /user/profile/ - меня перекидывает на index.php?do... ну вы поняли, по последнему правилу а не по тому что надо. Как обоити для этого?